# Как добавить переменную js в .prop()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно динамически изменять надпись кнопки.
Использую функцию jquery .prop().

```
$(".order-button").prop('value', 'Оформить заказ - sss');
```

где sss - должна быть переменная js.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".order-button").prop('value', 'Оформить заказ' + sss);
```

Космическая тупость)))

Answer (score -1):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

var sss = "#52";

function Update() {
  btn.innerText = "Take order - " + sss;
}

setInterval(Update, 100);
```

```html
<button id="btn"></button>
```